# My Teen Romantic Comedy: What did Yukinoshita mean "this will be the last one then you can end it."?

Tags: oregairu

In season 3 ep 5 of My Teen Romantic Comedy, we find after the ending that yukinoshita and Iroha are talking in the student council office and after a little conversing yukonishita states

"It's alright, this will be the last one, then you can end it" (dubbed)

"It's alright though, this will be the last one. I can truly end things with this" (subbed)

---

It could be explained in many different ways, but I'm asking this community because I haven't seen anyone ask this question on any forum for me to have different idea pools to pull from.
so please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She says it because she believes that she was depending on hikigaya in every difficult situation. she knew that hikigaya was doing this (another prom) for her sake and to solve the problem and she thought she will rely on him for the last time as after the prom they will end the club which was their only way of communicating and she will go alone again and wouldn't have to rely on him again